# Why can I do array[3].toUpperCase(), but array[n].toUpperCase() errors when n=3 (or any num)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a coding challenge in this specific way.

The goal is to capitalize every 2nd letter of a string.

When I run the code with letterArray[0] or any other number, the code runs PERFECTLY. but the moment I switch it to letterArray[n], the code crashes. The error message I get says:

> Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined.

Why is letterArray[n].toUpperCase() undefined, when letterArray[n].toUpperCase() is not? understanding the fundamentals is my real concern here.

```js
let theString = "abcdefghijklm" // good
let theStringLength = theString.length // good 
let letterArray = theString.split(""); // good
let newArray = []; // good
let i = 0; // good
let n = 1
for (let index = 0; index < theStringLength; index += 2) {
  let lowCaseLetter = letterArray[i]
  newArray += lowCaseLetter
  i += 2
  let upCaseLetter = letterArray[n].toUpperCase();
  //if i change this to letterArray[0] the code works perfectly
  newArray += upCaseLetter
  n += 2
}
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: `i` and `index` are always the same, and the loop only runs as long as `index < theStringLength`, so `i` is always in bounds. So far so good. But `n` is one greater than `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string has 13 characters. Your loop starts at 0, incrementing by 2 until it hits the limit, so it runs with values 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and 12. Your `n` also increments by 2, but starts from `1`, so `n` has the value 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, and 13. Index 13 is past the end of your array, so you read an `undefined` value, and try to call `toUpperCase` on it.

You need to fix your code such that you don't effectively *require* an even length input; as written, your code assumes it can always read one odd index for every even, when that will never be the case for odd length inputs.

One solution is to avoid trying to handle an even and odd in each loop, instead determining whether to uppercase as you go, e.g.:

```
for (let index = 0; index < theStringLength; ++index) {  // Only increment by 1
    let val = letterArray[index];  // Read out value
    if (index % 2 === 1) val = val.toUpperCase();  // Convert to upper case for odd indices
    newArray += val;  // Append to result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets refer to your code, you are running the loop `theStringLength` time, which denotes the length of the string, that's work as expected. However, as you are incrementing the variable i and n by the same number but with different initial value, that is where the error occurs, the value i stays within the bound as the initial value of `i` and `index` are same, if you change initial value of `i` to be 1 and `n` to be 0, it should throw same error for `i` now.

Hopes this explanation helps.

```
   let theString = "abcdefghijklm" // good
   let theStringLength = theString.length // good 
   let letterArray = theString.split(""); // good
   let newArray = []; // good
   let i = 0; // good
   let n = 1
   for (let index = 0; index < theStringLength; index += 2) {
     let lowCaseLetter = letterArray[i]
     newArray += lowCaseLetter
     i += 2
     let upCaseLetter = letterArray[n].toUpperCase();
     //if i change this to letterArray[0] the code works perfectly
     newArray += upCaseLetter
     n += 2
   }
   console.log(newArray)
```